# Java, why is someone doing this to the ternary operator?

Tags: java

Why would someone do this?

```
int foo;
foo = (true?this.getFoo() : 0); //getFoo() returns int
```

It's popping up a bunch, and I really just don't understand how this wouldn't always be equivalent to:

```
int foo = this.getFoo();
```

This is only being used on variables of type int, and using getters that return ints.  Strings don't get the same treatment.

Edit to include answer: (from a comment by Andy Turner)

> In terms of the question "is true ? getFoo() : 0 logically equivalent
>   to getFoo()": this is answered in the language spec, where it says:
>   "If the value of the first operand is true, then the second operand
>   expression is chosen." (and "The operand expression not chosen is not
>   evaluated for that particular evaluation of the conditional
>   expression", although it wouldn't matter in this case if the 0 were
>   evaluated and then discarded, since there is no side effect of
>   evaluating it)

Comment: it's will always be foo = this.getFoo(), unless they managed to change the value of true. maybe you should ask the person who wrote this code

Comment: What is the type of `this.getFoo()`?

Comment: this.getFoo() returns int

Comment: In that case your first port of call should be to ask the author. You have more context here than we do: we have no idea which piece of code you're looking at. Is it open source? Company code? Something else?

Comment: Author is gone to the wind, also, company code.

Comment: Pretty sure it will get optimized by the compiler anyways.

Comment: @Nathan probably the fact he wrote code like that is why he is gone with the wind

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's absolutely nothing that justifies using a ternary in that case.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little? E.g. point to the part of spec that clearly states that this expression is *always* rewritten to `this.getFoo()`, or show some decompiled examples?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin it's not always rewritten to that. It's just *there is no reason* to write this.

Comment: @AndyTurner You seem to conflate two vastly different realms here. "There is no reason" is a philosophical statement that seems to to say something about possible motivation of the person who wrote the piece of code. I can't say anything about that, maybe the person who wrote it gained some strange kind of pleasure from writing incomprehensible code. What I was looking for was a statement about the semantics of Java: "`true ? bar : baz` is always rewritten to `bar`" is a precise verifiable statement about the semantics of a programming language, it does not involve any psychology or philosophy

Comment: OK, here's a precise statement: `true ? bar : baz` is not required to be rewritten to that. You won't find anything in the spec which says it does that. The compiler or JIT might optimize it away, but it's not required to.

Comment: In terms of the question "is `true ? getFoo() : 0` *logically* equivalent to `getFoo()`": this is answered in the [language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25), where it says: "If the value of the first operand is true, then the second operand expression is chosen." (and "The operand expression not chosen is not evaluated for that particular evaluation of the conditional expression", although it wouldn't matter in this case if the `0` were evaluated and then discarded, since there is no side effect of evaluating it).

Comment: I can verify that the original author did indeed gain pleasure from writing incomprehensible code.

Comment: @AndyTurner From your answer, I see that the statement in your comment is true, whereas the statement in my previous comment is false. Thank you. However, I still don't approve of the wording in Shwarthog's answer. Maybe it would have worked as an argument from authority if it was stated as "*I* see absolutely nothing that justifies [...]" by someone with a golden Java badge, but as it is now, this answer is just a poorly justified belief. Even though it is probably true, the answer does not attempt to explain *why* it has to be true. I therefore upvote your answer as the more insightful one.

Answer (score 6):

If `this.getFoo()` is an `Integer`, `Short` or `Byte`, this can be triggering some of the perverse behavior around unboxing with the conditional operator.

For example, if `this.getFoo()` returns `null`, this expression results in a `NullPointerException`.

Other than for toy examples, there is no good reason to write this.

And if `this.getFoo()` returns a primitive type, there is absolutely no reason to write it. `foo = true ? this.getFoo() : 0;` is equivalent to `foo = this.getFoo()`.

The relevant section of the language spec is [Sec 15.25](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25), where it says:

> If the value of the first operand is true, then the second operand expression is chosen.

(It also says:

> The operand expression not chosen is not evaluated for that particular evaluation of the conditional expression

although it wouldn't matter in this case if the 0 were evaluated and then discarded, since there is no side effect of evaluating it).

---

The conditional operator has some very peculiar behavior around boxing and unboxing. For instance:

```
condition ? 0 : null
```

boxes the `0`, so always succeeds; but

```
condition ? 0 : (Integer) null
```

*unboxes* the `null`, and so will fail with `NullPointerException` when `condition` is false.

And, remarkably, the result of

```
true ? Integer.valueOf(0) : Double.valueOf(0)
```

is a `Double`.

It gets even more insidious with nested conditional expressions, e.g.

```
Integer i = condition1 ? 1 : condition2 ? 2 : null;
```

because the overall expression has type `int`, not `Integer`, so you can get a `NullPointerException`, even though it looks like you're getting an `Integer`, because you're assigning to a variable of type `Integer`. Actually, it's evaluated like this:

```
Integer i = Integer.valueOf(condition1 ? 1 : (condition2 ? Integer.valueOf(2) : null).intValue()));
```

The conditional operator has some pretty hairy rules, and should be used only with great care where boxed numeric types are involved.

Comment: in which scenario do you see int foo = (true ? this.getFoo() : null); not end in a NPE if this.getFoo() returns null?

Comment: @Stultuske poor wording. I meant that it does.

Comment: what does your first sentence mean, with regards to unboxing with the conditional

Comment: @Nathan I've expanded my answer with some examples.

Answer (score 3):

The ternary makes no sense : the condition is always true.

It is as if you had writen :

```
foo =  this.getFoo();
```

Here is an example where a ternary could make sense.
Suppose that `this.fetFoo()` returns an `Integer` that may be `null`, you could so write this code to prevent a `NullPointerException`:

```
int foo = this.getFoo() == null ? 0 : this.getFoo();
```

or without duplicate call to `this.getFoo()` but more verbose :

```
Integer fooInteger = this.getFoo();
int foo = fooInteger == null ? 0 : fooInteger;
```

Comment: Your code makes perfect sense. But it doesn't answer the question about the code that doesn't seem to make any sense at all.

Comment: @Andrey Tyukin  You are right. I reworded to explain the irrelevance and the introduction of a valid use case.

Comment: I'm familiar with this, but... would you want to handle this while using the getter?  why not in the getter itself?

Comment: Ideally yes. But it may not be possible/wished for multiple reasons : because some devs avoid logic in getters or because it is a  library code.